# Xamarin C# Two UITableViewCells in one UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am trying to put two different `UITableViewCell`'s into one `UITableView` however when I try to load data into a `TableSource` It only allows me to send one `List<>` at a time. However I need two `List<>`'s for both my Cells to display. The two Lists in my `TableSource.cs` class are public variables called instaData and faceData. When I run Individual requests for getting instaData and faceData it works flawlessly. Better shown then explained:

**Request for InstaData**

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");
    client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (response.Content);
        InstagramObject.next_url = rootObject.pagination.next_url.ToString();
        FLDTRequest.instagramDataCopy = rootObject.data;
        table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        table.Source = new TableSource(stream);
        ((TableSource)table.Source).instaData = rootObject.data;
        table.ReloadData ();
        });
    });
```

**Request for FaceData**

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://graph.facebook.com/");
                client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Floadt.Core.Facebook.RootObject> (response.Content);
                    FLDTRequest.facebookDataCopy = rootObject.data;
                    table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                        table.Source = new TableSource(stream);
                        ((TableSource)table.Source).faceData = rootObject.data;
                        table.ReloadData ();
                    });
                });
```

Basically I call both methods when I want to get both data but I usually get a error from the Method I call last saying that that Object is not a reference. For Example: If i call faceData request last it would say Object is not a reference. Here is my `TableSource` Class:

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource 
{
    StreamViewController controller;

    public List<Datum> instaData { get; set; }
    public List<string> twitData { get; set; }
    public List<Floadt.Core.Facebook.Datum> faceData { get; set; }

    public TableSource(StreamViewController stream)
    {
        controller = stream;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return faceData.Count;
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) {
            return 340;
        } else {
            return 436;
            //return 210;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) {
            NetworkCheck netCheck = new NetworkCheck ();
            netCheck.runCheck ();
            // bool log = netCheck.anyLoggedIn ();

            if (tableView.ContentSize.Height - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height <= tableView.ContentOffset.Y) {
                BTProgressHUD.Show ("Getting more...");
                FLDTRequest.getInstagramNextPage (tableView);
                BTProgressHUD.Dismiss ();
            }

            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (InstagramCell.Key) as InstagramCell;

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new InstagramCell ();
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("InstagramCell", cell, null);
                cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as InstagramCell;
            }

            //Datum h = instaData [indexPath.Row/2];
            //cell.BindData (h);

            return cell;

        } else {
            NetworkCheck netCheck = new NetworkCheck ();
            netCheck.runCheck ();
            // bool log = netCheck.anyLoggedIn ();

            if (tableView.ContentSize.Height - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height <= tableView.ContentOffset.Y) {
                BTProgressHUD.Show ("Getting more...");
                FLDTRequest.getInstagramNextPage (tableView);
                BTProgressHUD.Dismiss ();
            }


            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (FacebookCell.Key) as FacebookCell;

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new FacebookCell ();
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("FacebookCell", cell, null);
                cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as FacebookCell;
            }

            var fbPhotoCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (FacebookPhotoCell.Key) as FacebookPhotoCell;

            if (fbPhotoCell == null) {
                fbPhotoCell = new FacebookPhotoCell ();
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("FacebookPhotoCell", cell, null);
                fbPhotoCell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as FacebookPhotoCell;
            }

            Floadt.Core.Facebook.Datum f = faceData [indexPath.Row/2];

            fbPhotoCell.BindData (f);
            return fbPhotoCell;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific line is throwing the "object not a reference" exception?  The way your code is structured every time you load data it creates a new TableSource, so you will lose the data that already exists in TableSource.

Comment: @Jason Yeah i understand the problem Im very stumped in finding a way to solve because as the answer given below suggests I cant just make a single list because the class structures of the FB and Instagram data are very different

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to set `table.Source` twice, once for each `List`? You need to merge your lists into a single data source, and create a `UITableViewCell` that can visualize both data types.

Comment: I wouldnt be able to simply merge both lists because the classes that both the lists are based on are very very different and it would be very difficult to merge them..

Answer (score 0):

1)Drag and Drop UITableView to ViewController and add constraints.

2)Add two Prototype cells and Associate with Two UITableViewCells.

3) Set up UITableViewSource(Combines UITableVIewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate).

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad ();
                // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                this.sampleTableView.Source = new SampleTableViewSource ();     
            }
```

Add Source class to ViewController.

```
//Table Source
        public class SampleTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
        {
            string CellIdentifier = "sampleTableViewCellID";
            string CellIdentifier2 = "sampleTableViewCell2ID";

            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell ();

                //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one

                if (indexPath.Row == 0)
                    {
                    cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier) as SampleTableViewCell;               
                    }
                    else if(indexPath.Row == 1 ) {
                    cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier2) as sampleTableViewCell2;
                    }

                return cell;
            }
            public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        } 
        }
```